# AJAX Post array of objects to endpoint

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, object, post

I am trying to post an array of objects to an API endpoint `(onClick)` but I keep getting a **400 Bad Request** error.

I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong here and was hoping for some assistance with this issue please.

My code is as follows:

```
$('#test-post').on('click', function() {

          var postData = [
            {
              "artist": "Artist Name",
              "title": "Artist Title",
              "genre": "string",
              "duration": "2:05",
              "url": "Artist url",
            },
            {
              "artist": "Artist Name",
              "title": "Artist Title",
              "genre": "string",
              "duration": "2:05",
              "url": "Artist url",
            }
          ];

          $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/endpoint',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(postData),
            success: function(data) {
              console.log('Data has been posted');
              console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(err) {
              console.log(err.statusText);
            }
          });
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code. Seems JQuery was missing.

```js
$('#test-post').on('click', function() {

          var postData = [
            {
              "artist": "Artist Name",
              "title": "Artist Title",
              "genre": "string",
              "duration": "2:05",
              "url": "Artist url",
            },
            {
              "artist": "Artist Name",
              "title": "Artist Title",
              "genre": "string",
              "duration": "2:05",
              "url": "Artist url",
            }
          ];

          $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/endpoint',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'params': JSON.stringify(postData)},
            success: function(data) {
              console.log('Data has been posted');
              console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(err) {
              console.log("Error is: " + err.statusText);
            }
          });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test-post">Click me</div>
```

Endpoint URL has this simple code. And this works.
`<?php echo $_POST['params']; ?>`

Comment: I have jQuery placed in my footer before my site.js file. I don't think that is the issue. @milan-chheda

Comment: Can you check in console, if JQuery is getting loaded. Also, kindly share the HTML code to better understand the problem. You can try my above code, it doesn't throw 400 bad request.

Comment: I checked and jQuery is getting loaded. The html code only consists of the button with the id of `test-post`. If I run your snippet about it gives the following error: `Error is: error`

Comment: Yes and that `Error is: error` is written in the error callback. Can you verify that the requested URL is hit and it does return JSON?

Comment: Yes it does return JSON. I tried posting a single object like this `var postData = { "artist": "Artist Name", "title": "Artist Title", "genre": "string", "duration": "2:05", "url": "Artist url",  }` and this seems to post successfully

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP .Net MVC
Please check you are using correct filter use `[HttpPost]` for POST request by default it will consider its as `Get` request

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult endpoint()
```

Comment: I am not using ASP .Net. Just doing a post using jQuery AJAX